# Convert double timeformat with php MSSQL

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have here a problem to convert a time who is double with php. I´ve never seen it before.

Is this the timeformat from excel?
Is it possible to do it with the mssql server where the data is stored in?

Here are some time examples.

```
0.291666666666667 = 07:00:00
0.229166666666667 = 05:30:00
0.320833333333333 = 07:42:00
```

Comment: What are those numbers supposed to mean? Do you have the corresponding dates? As you mention Excel, maybe some other date format was converted to a number by error (because Excel has no understanding of the original format)?

Comment: Quick google search seems to indicate it might be from MS Access: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/210276/how-to-store--calculate--and-compare-date-time-data-in-microsoft-acces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing those are times? Use `CONVERT`:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(0.291666666666667),(0.229166666666667),(0.320833333333333))V(T))
SELECT T, CONVERT(time(0), CONVERT(datetime, t)) AS TimeValue
FROM VTE;
```

(2 conversions, as you can't convert straight from a `decimal` to a `time`)

Edit: Datetime values in Excel (and sql server) are actually stored as numerics. The value 0 for a `datetime` in SQL Server being `19000101` *(if I recall correctly, `0` is `19000100` in Excel/Access and `1` is `19000101`; just to make things a little confusing)*. Each full integer adds an extra day to the datetime 0. Thus a value of `1` is `19000102` and `5` would be `19000106`, etc, etc.

The same is true for the time portion, however, these are stored as the decimal part. Thus, `0.5` represents 12 hours. Thus, the value `0.5` represents `19000101 12:00:00.000`. `6.75` would be `19000107 18:00:00.000`. With Excel and Access, they also stores times as a decimal (between 0 and 1).  Hence, why the above works, as it firstly converts the decimal to a `datetime` (for the first value `19000101 07:00:00.000`) and then to a `time(0)` (0 represents 0 points of millisecond accuracy); resulting in `07:00:00`.

Comment: THANK YOU that is the solution

Comment: @Andy Then please mark it as so. :)

Comment: i need to wait 3 minutes :-)

Comment: Added a little explanation for  you as well.

Comment: @andy `time` is displayed in 24 hour format. All of the values you have supplied are prior to 12:00.